# Does an app name have to be unique between the iPhone and iPad app store?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, naming

If there was an iPhone app called 'gears' could I release a app for iPad called 'gears'?

Also, has anyone heard if Apple will move towards limiting unique names to a category so it would be possible e.g. 'gears' the game and 'gears' the productivity app?

App naming seems like a dark art. Any pointers to resources on Apple's stance would also be handy.

Comment: AFAIK, names must be unique across the whole app store. I don't know if it's a dark art beyond enforced uniqueness. It's of course your job to watch out for trademark violation if you have something new that is named to intentionally grab eyeballs from an existing app, etc.

Comment: Dark art in the way the way there's so no way of searching for names that have been reserved by other apps in approval process. Searching on the app store isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen many duplicate named apps. It probably all comes down to whether your AppName™ has a Superscript℠ after it in some Way©. If no one legally owns the name, I think you could use it with impunity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't like the look of Superscipt.

Comment: i dont mean actually having superscript in the name. I mean copyrighting or trademarking it so if someone else tries to use it or another party is using it, you have a better legal stance. Not sure it would help. Obbiously this is not paralegaloverflow.com ;)

Comment: :) I haven't seen any exact duplicates, if you point me in the right direction for one I will click the tick of glory for you.

Comment: There are 2 apps called "PhotoFrame" by different developers in the app store. That's just one example. There's others, but they seem to be cracking down.